# How to setting and sort row and column simutaneously

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2010, microsoft-excel-2007

From images below, the left is the base table and the right is the table that want to show. Here, what to I want is filter for both column and row. We do choose specific date (I did not put DATE variable because I do not know where to put the DATE VARIABLE for this case). For instance, we do choose 1/01/2022. Of course, for normal table, it will show ALL DATA for row 1/01/2022. But, I do also want to pick CODE PX1 in this case. Hence, it will only shown data for row 1/01/2022 and column PX1 which gives 1 (in green cell). So, question is, how to do it? Thank you.

[image]

Comment: I do meant filtering, not sorting. Thank you.

Comment: Welcome! Excel-2007? You will need the function `OFFSET(B4,...)` and two functions `MATCH(...,...,0)` - find the date in the range **B5:B10** and find `PX1` in the range **C2:E3**. You can use the same `OFFSET()` or `INDEX()` to style the subheadings of the second and third rows

Answer (score 0):

You can try the formula.

Such as the SumProduct function.

On my simple sample, the array formula is `=SUMPRODUCT(($A$4:$A$6=$G6)*($B$1:$D$1=H$3),$B$4:$D$6)`, and press Ctrl+Shift+Enter.

[image]